# How to make the text inside div stick to the left?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have setup a list of  tags inside an unordered list. I want this component to house a vertically aligned items on the side of the page.

**It currently looks like below:**

[image: MISALIGNED]

**Here's how the sidebar is currently setup:**

```
export default class SideBar extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="sidebar-container">
                <ul class="sidebar-list">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

with **css**

```
.sidebar-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    z-index: 999;
    // width: 20px;
}

.sidebar-container > ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-list > li {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
        -ms-writing-mode: tb-lr;
            writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    // background-color: pink;
    color: white;
}

.sidebar-list > li > a {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 16px;
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 5vh;
}
```

How can I stick it to the left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers give `ul`s a default padding (Chrome for example gives it 40px). You need to set that to 0 like this:

```
.sidebar-container > ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, couldn't you just used fixed?

```
.sidebar-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

It will be removed from the flex flow (I believe) so you might need to adjust some other bits and bobs based on that.

Answer (score 0):

`ul` has default padding you need to override it.
See here. http://jsfiddle.net/bhupendra_nitt/1dxt36sb/6/

Answer (score 0):

If you have not got a browser reset in your project you should do. Use normalize
https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ or something similar. Most of these issues will not be present for you after but I as everyone has said you need to remove the default padding from the `ul`